# Sending treeview information from button_press_event in pygtk

Tags: python, pygtk, gtktreeview

I am writing an pygtk app that uses a treeview, which has a connection to  `button_press_event`. What I can't figure out is how to pass the information about the treeview (specifically which row is clicked) to a `gtk.Menu` or another method. If I used the `row-activated` signal, it passes in the row and column information in as an argument, but this does not happen with `button_press_event`. Here is the code in question:

```
    self.liststore = gtk.ListStore(str,int, int, int,str, 'gboolean')
    self.treeview = gtk.TreeView(self.liststore)

    self.treeview.connect("button_press_event",self.serverListEvent)
    self.treeview.set_search_column(0)
    self.draw_columns(self.treeview)

    self.blackmenu = gtk.Menu()
    self.bitem = gtk.MenuItem("Blacklist server")
    self.blackmenu.append(self.bitem)
    self.bitem.connect("activate",self.blacklistServer)
    self.bitem.show()

def serverListEvent(self,treeview,event):
    x = int(event.x)
    y = int(event.y)
    time = event.time
    model = treeview.get_model()

    pthinfo = treeview.get_path_at_pos(x, y)
    if pthinfo is not None:
        path, col, cellx, celly = pthinfo
        # Error here for the model with the column
        print 'url clicked '+model[col][0]
        treeview.grab_focus()
        treeview.set_cursor( path, col, 0)
        # Popup blacklist menu on right click
        if event.button == 3:            
            self.blackmenu.popup( None, None, None, event.button, time)
        # Join game on double click
        elif event.type == gtk.gdk._2BUTTON_PRESS:
            self.joinGame(treeview,model[col][0])
    return True
```

I then need to pass the information from the clicked row to the `self.joinGame` and `self.blacklistServer` methods, but don't know how to do this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember that one being kindy tricky. I [set up my treeview's gtk.TreeSelection](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeselection.html#method-gtktreeselection--set-mode) to whatever [mode of selection](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gtk-constants.html#gtk-selection-mode-constants) preferred. Then this:

```
def get_selected_ids(self):
    ids = []
    store, paths = self.get_selection().get_selected_rows()

    # self.adapter is a mapping class from my data-model to a model column index.
    # If you know the column index from your gtk.ListStore, you don't need it.
    colindex = self.adapter.get_column_modelindex("id")

    for path in paths:
        treeiter = store.get_iter(path)
        # Pull value from liststore
        val = store.get_value(
            treeiter, 
            colindex
        )
        ids.append(val)
    return ids
```

Edit:

I never used gtk.Menu and gtk.MenuItem, so I didn't get that you already had your menu connected to a callback (*blacklistServer*). This is untested, but should give you an idea.

```
def blacklistServer(self, menuitem, *ignore):
    # you have to modify *get_selected_ids* so it returns the values you need for
    # blacklisting.
    values = self.get_selected_ids()
    blacklist = set(values)
    self.saveBlacklist(blacklist)
```

Comment: How do I pass this information about what row is selected to the popup menu?

Comment: 2 ways I can think of: you could register a custom signal with the treeview and have your popup listen to that. Or if you keep a reference to your popup you can set the value directly or with a method on it.

Comment: Can you give some example code because I am really stuck here.

Comment: Please see my edit. Are you asking about the *joinGame* method as well?